# In every infinite-dimensional TVS, every w-neighborhood of 0 contains an infinite-dimensional subspace (Rudin's FA, p. 66))

Tags: functional-analysis

In Rudin's Functional Analysis, second edition, p. 66 I bumped into the following proposition: *If X is infinte-dimensional [topological vector space with a dual that separates points on X] then every weak neighborhood of $\mathbf{0}$ contains an infinite-dimensional subspace.*

The proof of this claim goes like this: suppose $V$ is a neighborhood of the form
$$
V = \{x \in X : |\Lambda_i x| < \epsilon_i \text{ for } 1 \leq i \leq n \},
$$
where $\Lambda_i \in X^{*}$ and $\epsilon_i > 0$ (this $V$ is in fact a generic member of the local basis for the weak topology $\tau_w$ introduced a few lines earlier in the same book) and define
$$
N = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} \ker \Lambda_i.
$$
Since the map $x \mapsto (\Lambda_1 x, \Lambda_2 x, \ldots, \Lambda_n x)$ maps $X$ to $\Phi^{n}$ (here $\Phi$ denotes the scalar field which is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) with null space $N,$ we see that $\dim X \leq n + \dim N.$ Since $N \subset V,$ the result follows.

The things I would like to understand better are the following:

- Where does the formula $\dim X \leq n + \dim N$ come from and why there is only $\leq$ in it instead of $=$?
- Do I have it right that, taking the above inequlity for granted, if we suppose $\dim X = \infty$ then of course $n + \dim N$ must be $\infty$ and since $n$ is already chosen and kept fixed, then $\dim N$ must be $\infty$ which is the very point as I guess?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second question: yes, that's right.

Why is it $\le$: The $\Lambda_j$ may not be independent.

Where does the inequality come from:

Let $V=T(X)$. There exists a linear map $S:V\to X$ such that $$TSv=v\quad(v\in V).$$(Say $b_1,\dots,b_m$ is a basis for $V$. For each $j$ choose $x_j\in X$ with $Tx_j=b_j$. Define $S(\sum c_jb_j)=\sum c_j x_j$.)

So $$TSTx=Tx\quad(x\in X).$$This says $$x-STx\in N\quad(x\in X).$$But $$x=STx+(x-STx)$$and $STx\in S(V)$. So $$(v,y)\mapsto y+Sv$$is a linear map from $V\oplus N$ *onto* $X$. So $$\dim(X)\le\dim(V\oplus N)=m+\dim(N)\le n+\dim(N).$$

Or see the rank-nullity theorem...

Comment: That helped a lot, thank you.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, why  $ m \leq n$?

Comment: @Mathenthusiast Hmm, looks like I never defined $T$, oops. In fact $Tx=(\Lambda_1x,\dots,\Lambda_nx)$. So $TX\subset\Phi^n$, hence $m=dim(TX)\le n$.

Comment: Just more one question: is it sufficient show that $\dim (X) \leq m + \dim (N)$ in order to show that N is infinite-dimensional by the same argument of the OP's author, isn't it?